# I just installed Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox. How do I access the install?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I created a virtual machine in VirtualBox, and then ran the Ubuntu installer within the virtual machine. I was able to run Ubuntu immediately after installation. However, if I try to switch back to my virtual hard disk as the boot disk, VirtualBox complains that it can't boot from the chosen device.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox, or VMware (I use this) or other virtualizing app does not make a dual boot environment. You cannot boot the virtual disk in a standard way. You start it with (in this case) VirtualBox. That is how you set it up and it is apparently running that way (according to what you said above).

You can download the ISO from Ubuntu.com to use in creating a virtual machine. I have done this.

You can create a Raw Image that you can start with VirtualBox, but virtual machines are easier.

Here is a [tutorial](https://technomagus.wordpress.com/linux/virtual-machines/virtualbox/raw-disk-to-virtualbox-image/) for using a Raw Disk.

> First you should make a copy of raw disk, and store it as a file. This
> is done with `dd`. Remember that it is not advisable to copy a running
> filesystem, so the best way is to boot your machine with SystemRescueCd
> or some live USB/CD.
>
> Conversion is done with the VirtualBox utility VBoxManage. .....
>
> Now you can add this virtual_disk as a VirtualBox machine.

Finally if you wish to boot Ubuntu entirely separately, use a dual boot.  I much prefer virtual machines to dual booting.

Comment: OK, so I should have an Ubuntu OS image ready to go? How do I get one?

Comment: Use a download (ISO) File from Ubuntu to make a virtual machine.    Or you can create a Raw Image that you can run in Virtual Box.  Virtual Machines are easier.  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html